Can one use asymptotic behaviour to deduce the induced distribution from a function?
As an example, imagine I have $e^{i\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot k}$ defined for $x$ on the reals. Then, in a distributional sense, I want to understand
$$\int e^{i\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot k} dx$$
My naive approach would be to "add and subtract" the large $x$ behaviour to get a convergent integral + distribution, i.e.
$$e^{i\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot k}=e^{ixk}+\frac{iky^2}{2x}e^{ixk}+\mathcal{O}(1/x^2)$$
So I add and subtract to $\int e^{i\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot k} dx$ the term $\int e^{ixk} dx$, such that I am left with
$$\int e^{ixk} dx+\int e^{i\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot k} - e^{ixk} dx$$
where the first term, I know how to deal with, and the second I know from the previous analysis, will converge, since it drops as $1/x$, but has an oscillatory part.
Is this a legit way to deal with these types of integrals? Since strictly speaking, I am adding and subtracting infinities.

Yes, in a distributional sense means: "multiplied with any test function and then integrated". The terms you are manipulating are defined in that sense. Also they are not infinite when used like that, so you are not adding and subtracting infinities.
Of course it requires the choice of test functions to be sufficiently restricted to remove the infinities. This means that if you say "in a distributional sense" one might ask "which distributions? Based on which test functions?". Without further specification most people probably agree that the standard choice would be the Schwartz functions. (Appropriate because Laurent Schwartz is a Fields Medalist who wrote the famous book that placed distributions on the map, and can be read in the original French edition since between the equations only a few French words are used!)

That makes sense. And I am also allowed to expand in large x behaviour since this can be done in ordinary integrals as well? I will mark this answer as right if no one objects. Since I do not know anything at all.
